# extruding a polygon in 3D

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d

Using an array with the x,y coordinates of every edge I can draw a 2D polygon.
After that i want to extrude it in 3D.
I thought of a way to do this by adding depth to the array of the vertexes I have, first I draw with line strips and glvertex3f the bottom of my shape at x,y,0 ,then I redraw with x,y, 0.8 (0.8 is the added depth) and finally I join the edges with a line for every edge from x,y,0 to x,y,0.8

```
glPushMatrix();

glColor3f(color_outline.red, color_outline.green, color_outline.blue);
int i = 0;

glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);

for (i = 0; i < coord_iterator; i++)
{

    glVertex3f((float)mouse_x_coord[i], (float)mouse_y_coord[i],0);

    newx[i] = (float)mouse_x_coord[coord_iterator];
    newy[i] = (float)mouse_y_coord[coord_iterator];

}

newx[coord_iterator] = (float)mouse_x_coord[coord_iterator];
newy[coord_iterator] = (float)mouse_y_coord[coord_iterator];

glEnd();

glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);

glVertex3f((float)mouse_x_coord[i - 1], (float)mouse_y_coord[i - 1],0);
glVertex3f((float)mouse_x_coord[i], (float)mouse_y_coord[i],0);
glVertex3f((float)mouse_x_coord[0], (float)mouse_y_coord[0],0);

glEnd();



glPopMatrix();

glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);

for (i = 0; i<coord_iterator; i++)
{
    glVertex3f(newx[i], newy[i],0.8);

}

glEnd();

glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
glVertex3f(newx[i-1], newy[i-1],0.8);
glVertex3f(newx[i], newy[i],0.8);
glVertex3f(newx[0], newy[0],0.8);

printf("newx %d newy %d", newx[i], newy[i]);

glEnd();

glPopMatrix();



for (i = 0; i<=coord_iterator; i++)
{
    glBegin(GL_LINE);
    glVertex3f(newx[i], newy[i],0.8);
    glVertex3f((float)mouse_x_coord[i],(float)mouse_y_coord[i],0.8);
    glEnd();

}


glutSwapBuffers(); //swap the buffers
```

My problem now is that i cant see it in 3d, i have initialized my window 
with

```
gluOrtho2D(0.0f, (float)window_width, 0.0f, (float)window_height);
```

but gluOrtho2D actually calls

```
 void gluOrtho2D(
    GLdouble left,
    GLdouble right,
    GLdouble bottom,
    GLdouble top )
    {
    glOrtho(left, right, bottom, top, -1, 1);
    }
```

that means i have a 3D system with -1 to 1 depth but all i can see is the polygon i drew before

Comment: You have a bunch of glPopMatrix(); without any glPushMatrix() calls.

Comment: @bernie removed them, no difference at all